# Как настроить tsconfig для React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

Есть проект на typescript + react, в котором у меня вылетает ошибка

> All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is
> provided.

Что бы ее исправить, надо в tsconfig, `isolatedModules` сделать `false`. Я так и делаю, но когда, запуская проект с помощью `npm start`, файл перезаписывается, и возвращает `--isolatedModules` в `true`. Как сделать что бы это не происходило? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Не сталкивался на практике с этим флагом, но что стоит в `compilerOptions.module`?

Comment: в `compilerOptions.module` стоит `esnext`

Comment: Вот попробуй на `commonjs` поменять. Что-то говорит мне, что где-тут есть связь :) Скажи только, что потом произошло.

Comment: в том та и проблема, я поменял, но при запуске(`npm start`) он автоматически файл tconfig возвращает в изначальное состояние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании приложения командой

```
npx create-react-app xxx --template typescript
```

создаётся `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Дополнительную информацию (доп. настройка линтера и т.п.) почитать по ссылке [Adding TypeScript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/)

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!!!

Comment: ты, это, главное - не изобретай велосипед. мой посыл был не в конфиге, а в `npx create-react-app xxx --template typescript`